# Fancybox 2 renders weird in Chrome, but in Firefox and Opera works fine

Tags: google-chrome, fancybox

I spent half of the day to make fancybox 2.1.5 work in Chrome having Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) under Ubuntu Linux 14.04.
Firefox and Opera render iframe properly, but in Chrome I get weird result. The frame size is lesser then div's size that contains the frame. 
The actual size is 800x600, but I get iframe size about 300x150.  It's also not centered on the screen.

I tried to load jquery from CDN and via https, it doesn't matter.
I also tried to remove all my css with no success.
There are also no errors in JS console.

**-- Update --**

As you can see I tried different variants, I included optional fancybox stuff, I tried different versions of jquery, I moved the stuff from the bottom of body section to head, I removed all fancybox parameters, I tried it also with only width & height properties. And the result is FF and Opera works, but Chrome doesn't in all the cases (. Some parameters like      `autoCenter`, `autoScale` a little bit change the behavior but it doesn't matter.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js') }}"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/lib/alertify.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/lib/jquery.slides.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $(".signup-form").fancybox({
            autoSize: false,
            fitToView: false,
            width: 813,
            height : 603,
            minWidth: 813,
            minHeight : 603,
            autoCenter: false,
            autoScale: false,
            autoDimensions: false,
            type: "iframe"
//                afterLoad: function () {
//                    this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
//                    this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
//                }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  ...
<!-- trigger -->
    <div class="sign-up"><a class="signup-form" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="/signup" id="global-signup-link"><span>Sign up</span></a></div>
  ...
</body>
```

Thanx in advance.

[image]

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: Hi, again, could you please tell me, what is wrong with the question?